# How can I have a formula follow a specific pattern in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to consolidate the daily ledger for a business to have a weekly sales category, however I am unable to continue the formula for summing the daily sales for a week. Is there a way I can have excel follow a pattern such as:

| A | Date: | Daily Sales | Week of: | Weekly Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1/3 | 10 | 1/3-1/9 | =sum(A2:A8) |
| 3 | 1/4 | 15 | 1/10-1/16 | =sum(A9:A15) |

Rather than enter hundreds of formulas by hand I would like to have excel follow the rule of taking the next 6 cells in order to find the weekly total. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Use INDEX()

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*7+2):INDEX(A:A,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*7+8))
```

Put that in the first cell and copy down.

INDEX, Unlike OFFSET and INDIRECT (which both can be used here), is not Volatile.